# How to prevent misuse of rights in monitoring application?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, authentication, monitoring

I have a monitoring application that runs on the computer of each user in my organization. This application needs to insert some monitoring data in several tables of a database (MS SQL Server 2008 R2). We are using Windows authentication.

If I give INSERT rights or grant access to execute a stored procedure, how will I make sure that the users cannot misuse these rights and say for example, add a lot of unwanted data in the tables?

Comment: I believe you have given read write access on the Database to that application only, not to other users. Just see the roles given on that application and the one for users in question, role assigned to users should be read if you don't want users to modify any data on that specific database.

Comment: And to prevent you can use trace events and triggers as per you're need.

Comment: Instead of giving them insert rights to the base table, only give them rights to execute the stored procedure that does this. In any case, you can very easily log who is inserting data (even without a stored procedure, you can use a trigger). If a user is doing malicious things, you will have evidence.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to not grant the table at all, not to end users. Create a stored procedure that does the dml and grant the procedure to the monitoring users, not to the regular users. That way no misuse is possible.